# Django: ListView with post() method?

Tags: python, django, formview, django-class-based-views

I am trying to process two forms in a Django class based view. The site contains a form called `form` (based on `GET`) for narrowing the list results of the ListView and the second form `status_form` (based on `POST`).

Both forms are required since the ListView returns a list of items. `Form` lets the user restrict the choices and `status_forms` lets the user flag incorrect items via a modal form (therefore it needs to be in the same template).

My trouble is that `ListView` does not come with the method `post`, however `FormView` does. My class `List` inherits from both classes, but when I execute the class I get the error message:

> **Attribute Error: 'List' object has no attribute 'status_form'**

**How should I change my implementation to allow the second form been processed via the `post method`?**

```
class List(PaginationMixin, ListView, FormMixin):
    model = ListModel
    context_object_name = 'list_objects'
    template_name = 'pages/list.html'
    paginate_by = 10 #how may items per page

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.form = ListSearchForm(self.request.GET or None,)
        return super(List, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.status_form = StatusForm(self.request.POST or None)
        if self.status_form.is_valid():
            ...
        else:
            return super(List, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # define the queryset
        ...
        # when done, pass to object_list
        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(List, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form
        context['status_form'] = self.status_form # Django is complaining that status_form is not existing, result since the post method is not executed
        return context
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# Django is complaining that status_form does not exist,
# result since the post method is not executed
context['status_form'] = self.status_form
```

Because you didn't define `self.status_from` in the first place.
You have defined it in `get_context_data`, and it's accessible from there.

You can access you object from `get_context_data` in your post method;

```
context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
status_form = context['status_form']
```

Also consider that you can define your `status_form` directly in `post` method itself without getting it from `self` or `get_context_data`.

Redesign you views to separate each Form processing in separate Views then tight them with each-other.

Views redesign:

In nutshell, let each view to do one job. You can create a View just for processing your `status_form` and name it like `StatusFormProcessView` then on your `List` view return it on its `post` method

```
class List(ListView);
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return StatusFormView.as_view()(request) # What ever you need be pass to you form processing view
```

This is just an example of it, need more work to be real.

For another example; On my website index page I have a search form. when user `POST` or `GET` the search form, The processing of searching doesn't exist in my `IndexView`, instead I handle the whole form stuff in separate view, If form should process on `GET` method, I'll override `get()` method, If form should process on `POST`, I'll override `post()` method to send `search_form` data to the view that is responsible for handling of processing the `search_form`.

#### Comments response

`status_form = context['status_form']`

shouldn't it be

```
context['status_form'] = status_form
```

after I created it ?

You want to get `status_form` from `context`, So you need to

```
status_form = context['status_form']
```

Anyway, your form data are available on `self.request.POST`

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean with redesign the views? I am confused with the line status_form = context['status_form'], shouldn't it be context['status_form'] = status_form after I created it? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: When doing something like you suggest, and passing off to `return StatusFormView.as_view(request)` I get `TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: 2 minutes later... that line should be: `return StatusFormView.as_view()(request)`

Comment: @PhilGyford thanks for the suggested fix. I've updated the answer with your suggestion.