# Django Class Based view calling an other one

Tags: django

I develop a Class Based View to render a list of elements that you can see below:

```
class ConfirmBeforeRunTest(LoginRequiredMixinRedirect,ListView):
    template_name = "app_testing_house/confirm_before_run.html"
    # Redirect to login page if not auth
    redirect_unauthenticated_users = True

    # Options for ListView
    model = Test

    context_object_name = 'test_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Test.objects.filter()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return TestToRunPostProcessorView.as_view(request)
```

As you can see, I want to be able to handle POST request processing in my view in order get some arguments for my queryset. I once read a blog saying that one CBV = one function. So i created an other view, to handle all the POST process:

```
class TestToRunPostProcessorView(FormView):
    form_class = TestToRunForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Process form
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I get the following error message:

```
as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

So I assume `return TestToRunPostProcessorView.as_view(request)` is not correct but I don't know why..

Comment: I can't understand why you are doing this. If your list view processes some parameters, you should do it in that view, not by calling another one.

Comment: I was following the answer from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622354/django-listview-with-post-method. Since then I changed my mind and decided to process this data in the view directly.

Answer (score 5):

The function .as_view() in itself gives back a view function. You have to supply the parameters this way:

```
return TestToRunPostProcessorView.as_view()(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think `Listview` has a post method.

If you want to change the list based on a user input then you have a few different options.

If, for example, you are listing `Test` items based upon its category you could do:

```
# urls.py
...
    url(regex=r'^category/(?P<category_name>[\w.-]+)/$',
        view=ListByCategory.as_view(),
        name='single_category_list'),

# views.py

class ListByCategory(ListView):
    model = Test
    template_name = 'list_single_category.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.category = get_object_or_404(Category,
                                          category=self.kwargs['category_name'])

        return super(ListByCategory, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListByCategory, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = self.category
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ListByCategory, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(category=self.category)
```

Alternatively, if you want to filter the queryset based upon a submitted input then there is a great example in the book "Two Scoops of Django" which I would **highly recommend**.

I will not go into all the details but you do add something like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(ConfirmBeforeRunTest, self).get_queryset()
    q = self.request.GET.get("q")
    if q:
        return queryset.filter(field__contains=q)
    return queryset
```

I strongly recommend you to get the book. It will explain it in a lot more detail and give you a lot more options to use it effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code:

```
deprecated_urls = {
   'blog-v1-old-slug': BlogIndexView.as_view(),
   'blog-v2-old-slug': BlogIndexView.as_view(),
}

def route_slug_url(request, slug):
    # 1) match with Node (dynamic slug)
    try:
        nodeslug = NodeSlug.objects.get(slug=slug)
        return BlogNodeView.as_view()(request, node=nodeslug.node)
    except NodeSlug.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    # 2) match with NodeAuthor (dynamic slug)
    try:
        author = NodeAuthor.objects.get(slug=slug)
        return BlogAuthorView.as_view()(request, author=author)
    except NodeAuthor.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    # 3) match with deprecated URL (hard-coded)
    try:
        view = deprecated_urls[slug](request, slug=slug)
        return view
    except KeyError:
        pass

    return serve_404_response(request)

# at end of urls.py, add catch-all for matching slugs
urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    # How to reconcile with local slugs and node slugs?
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\/\s]+)/$', route_slug_url, name='build-slug'),
)
```