# ListView with different outputs depending on POST or GET

Tags: python, django

My app is a db of entries that can be filtered and grouped in lists. Index page should show all entries properly paginated, with no filters, and a search form to filter by entry name and types. Is there a way to do this with one ListView and one template, changing behaviors depending if the page was accessed from index (with GET) or from a search (with POST)? If so, how can I change template page title to "Index" or "Search results" accordingly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: ListView with post() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622354/django-listview-with-post-method)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `get()` and `post()` methods inside your view? It is exatcly what you need.

```
class YourView(ListView):
    ...
    def get(self, request):
        # unique behaviour for GET

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # unique behaviour for POST
```

Check out [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/).

Comment: Hello @NixonSparrow **ListView** don't have **post()** method

Comment: Hi @AnkitTiwari according to DOCS I've linked you can use it like this.

Comment: I have also used that solution in my applications many times. So yeah, it works with generic ListView.